# Adding Robotium for all test projects

Tags: eclipse, robotium, android-sdk-tools

Every time while i test the application using Robotium , i need to navigate to test project properties and add it to the project,whenever i am configuring new test projects i need to add it every time

is it there any other way to install Robotium and use default with my test project?

Comment: Is `tested.project.dir` of any use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191807/android-test-project-fails-to-build-under-ant-ok-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

There is no really simple way that I know of. The only way way is to make a sort of project template within your preferred IDE or have a set of maven/gradle build scripts that have a common set up for you to start from every time you make a new project.